# I ran maven as root one time and now can't run it normally

Tags: linux, maven

Using `mvn install` this is the error I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

I tried making myself the owner of my home directory, ~/.m2 folder, maven install, and everywhere else I could think of. How can I figure out where that class is?

Comment: With `find` or `locate`. See accompanying manual pages for more information about details.

Comment: which maven version are you using?

Comment: I think was using 3.1.1-- I forgot to follow up on this after I figured it out. I was missing the right environment variables. I had them defined in the root bashrc but not for the user.